# How to code a way of directly writing a sequence of observations

Tags: symbols, mathtools

I am trying to code my one notation such that I do not want to repeat every time I need to introduce a new sequence. I thought of coding it this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\sequence1{\{}{\}_{i=1}^{n}}

\begin{document}
    \[\sequence1{X_i}\]
\end{document}
```

For some reason this is not working for me. Can some one help

I am expecting to code `\sequence1{X_i}` and it gives me `$\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}` on latex.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as removing the number from the command sequence name.

[image: delimiter]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\sequence{\{}{\}_{i=1}^{n}}

\begin{document}
    \[\sequence{X_i}\]
\end{document}
```